# Focusrite Sapphire PRO 14 - Firewire card doesn't work after update

Tags: audio

I've used ElementaryOS for quite a while without a single glitch, but just recently I've noticed that my Focusrite Sapphire PRO 14 doesn't work anymore.
When the system boot I can see the FW (firewire) led blink for a few instants and then it turns off.

I tried a little bit of everything but nothing seems to work.

One very curious fact is that Zoom (Videochat app) seems to be able to wake up the hardware (FW led on) and I'm able to use the audio card (just in zoom).
The other audio card works well (motherboard's audio card).
On Windows 10 everything works perfectly, I guess it's a driver or misconfiguration issue.

```
$ lspci -knnvvv
...
20:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: Texas Instruments XIO2213A/B/XIO2221 IEEE-1394b OHCI Controller [Cheetah Express] [104c:823f] (rev 01) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: Device [3412:7856]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 32 (500ns min, 1000ns max), Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 36
    Region 0: Memory at f7204000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Region 1: Memory at f7200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci
    Kernel modules: firewire_ohci
...
```

```
$ lsmod | grep firewire                
snd_firewire_lib       40960  1 snd_dice
snd_rawmidi            36864  4 snd_seq_midi,snd_firewire_lib,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_dice
snd_pcm               102400  7 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_firewire_lib,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_dice
firewire_ohci          40960  0
firewire_core          65536  3 snd_firewire_lib,firewire_ohci,snd_dice
crc_itu_t              16384  1 firewire_core
```

```
$ dmesg | grep -i firewire 
[    1.069283] firewire_ohci 0000:20:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    1.128106] firewire_ohci 0000:20:00.0: added OHCI v1.10 device as card 0, 8 IR + 8 IT contexts, quirks 0x2
[    1.656201] firewire_core 0000:20:00.0: created device fw0: GUID 7856341278563412, S800
[    1.656206] firewire_core 0000:20:00.0: phy config: new root=ffc1, gap_count=5
[    6.894652] firewire_core 0000:20:00.0: created device fw1: GUID 00130e0402402b92, S400
[ 4589.883946] Modules linked in: xt_conntrack xt_MASQUERADE nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 br_netfilter bridge stp llc iptable_filter bpfilter aufs overlay binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(OE) nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) nvidia(POE) snd_usb_audio snd_usbmidi_lib drm_kms_helper uvcvideo drm videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common videodev mc ipmi_devintf snd_hda_codec_hdmi ipmi_msghandler snd_hda_codec_realtek fb_sys_fops edac_mce_amd syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt joydev input_leds snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio kvm_amd snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_dice snd_firewire_lib snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event kvm snd_rawmidi snd_hwdep snd_seq irqbypass snd_pcm snd_seq_device snd_timer crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 k10temp snd ccp soundcore crypto_simd cryptd eeepc_wmi wmi_bmof asus_wmi
[ 4589.883986]  mac_hid sparse_keymap video glue_helper sch_fq_codel nfsd parport_pc ppdev auth_rpcgss nfs_acl lockd lp grace parport sunrpc ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs xor zstd_compress raid6_pq libcrc32c dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid igb firewire_ohci firewire_core i2c_piix4 dca nvme crc_itu_t i2c_algo_bit ahci libahci nvme_core wmi gpio_amdpt gpio_generic
[ 4591.279078] firewire_core 0000:20:00.0: rediscovered device fw0
[ 4591.279081] firewire_core 0000:20:00.0: phy config: new root=ffc1, gap_count=5
[ 4596.509583] firewire_core 0000:20:00.0: created device fw1: GUID 00130e0402402b92, S400
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you don't use ffado. Instead, you are using the driver snd_dice that is included by default in the linux kernel (DICE is the chipset used in some Focusrite and Presonus Firewire audio interfaces).
i don't know all the details, but I understand that snd_dice has some severe limitations. If you have made some changes in your interface settings (say under Windows 10), the driver might be struggling to communicate.
Is the interface not visible as a possible output in the sound system preferences?
If not, I would try two things:
1/ reset your interface settings and re-try in elementary
2/ (can be tricky and mess up your system a bit) install ffado and jack sound server. ffado should become the driver for your interface, but you need to blacklist snd_dice as there is a risk of driver conflict...

Thanks, Marc

Comment: I actually installed ffado but it never appeared, probably I have to blacklist snd_dice.

Comment: The interface appears in my sound system preferences.